# What is difference between moss and sharepoint server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, moss, difference

The interviewer has asked me this question. Can anyone please let me know what is basically moss ? Why we should use moss ? When one should use moss over sharepoint 2010 ? Apart from some more and less features what are the differences between them ?

Answer (score 0):

MOSS = Microsoft Office SharePoint Server. So MOSS 2007 is SharePoint 2007. Differences can be found in the usual places.